# Landscape only iOS app not displaying correctly (NOT shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation related)

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, uiimageview, orientation

First off, here's what it looks like, the top one is what I have laid out in my NIB file and the second one is how it's displayed:

[image: second one]

I am not sure why the background is offset and why my images are not constrained to the size of the UIImageView that contains them.  Does anyone have an idea of what's going on?  I don't think I would need to reframe the controls, labels, etc. since those appear in the correct location.  Would this be an autosizing issue?  I went through all of the NIB's and unchecked `Autoresize Subview` for each one and then went through all of the images in each view and unchecked `Autoresize Subview` and that seemed to resize the images so they're smaller but still not staying in the bounds and sizing constraints of the `UIImageViews` that contain them.

Anyone have an idea of what's going on?

---

### Update

---

Here's images of what the app looks like now after unchecking all of the `Autoresize Subview` check boxes:

[image: after unchecking]

The sliders shouldn't be that close to the images either...

Comment: Is that Xcode 3.x?? If so, an update to 4.x with it's integrated interface builder might be just what you are looking for.  If not, maybe it's possible your XIB doesn't have the right rect of an iPad, or your UIView doesn't have the landscape option checked in IB.

Comment: This is Xcode 3.2.6.  I'll try and see what happens with Xcode 4, is there a lot of bugs with IB in 3.2.6?

Comment: I was using Xcode 3.2.6, I tried building it with Xcode 4.0.2 and it's still showing up the same.  Is the only landscape option in the `Attribute Inspector` under `Simulated Metrics`?  If my XIB's don't have the correct dimensions for an iPad would I have to reframe all of the elements?  I don't see how that would be though because when I created this project I built it for an iPad

Comment: In UIView's metrics, there should be a drop down for the orientation.  Change it to landscape and build.  Although it is highly recommended by apple that you support all orientations, such is not always the case.  Also check that your view controller is not returning YES for all orientations in -shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation.

Comment: Yeah I've done both of those.  I'm really starting to think that I might need to redo all of the views from scratch :c  I reallllly don't want to do that

Comment: I realized to save time I copy and pasted from the first view I set up into the next, just because there were a lot of labels, switches, sliders and photos for each view.  That doesn't seem to me like that would make a difference, but I'm still relatively new to iOS, maybe it would?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I ended deleting all of the `NIB's` and `header/implementation` files for all of the `ViewControllers`, just to be safe.  I remade all of the views and turned off `Resize view from NIB` for each `ViewController`, and then Photoshopped each image I was using to make sure that it was the size of the `ImageViews` I was using.  Still not quite sure what happened but redoing everything, changing the image sizes and unchecking `Resize view from NIB` seemed to do the trick.